# how to use long long keyword in Turbo C++ 3.2 compiler

Tags: c++, dos, unsigned-long-long-int

I am doing some emnedded work for which I am writing program in CPP. My machine has dos platform. In my program I am using long long keyword which is not working.I am using turboC++ 3.2 compiler.

I have searched a lot and find C99 library has stdint.h file but how can i use this file with my compiler.
Or some other comiler to work on embedded keywords which made dos based executable file.

Comment: Please clarify "long long keyword which is *not working*".  Is it compiling?  Does it not have the expected range?  Does it only work for even numbers?

Comment: The ancient compiler you're using doesn't support the `long long` type nor does it support any 64-bit integer type. You'll need to port the program to use 32-bit integer types (or maybe a floating-point type). That may mean writing your own code to do 64-bit arithmetic using 32-bit integers.

Comment: Why Turbo C++? That's ancient and doesn't support any of the new C++ standards. If you're writing embedded code you'll want the best compiler you can get to crank out the most optimized, minimal binary.

Comment: @tadman Probably working on some legacy product would be my guess so they might not have a choice.

Comment: @Javia1492 There's been a rash of these "Turbo C++" questions lately, so I'm trying to figure out why. Even then, there are vastly better compilers for doing legacy work, like Open Watcom.

Comment: @tadman: Indian schools teach use of Turbo C++ on DOS.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yupes it is compiling but it's range is of unsigned long.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That would explain. I have no idea why they'd subject people to this and expect them to learn anything about proper C++ development. C++ in the 1990s was an ugly beast.

Comment: The guy who ported Retro City Rampage to DOS [talks about his experience with DOS compilers](http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1023270/From-PS4-to-1-44MB) and working within really tight memory limits. Working within those super tight constraints is the sort of thing most people spend their entire career trying to avoid.

Comment: Just a minor point. `long long` is not a keyword; it's two keywords, both of them being `long`.

Comment: If you switch to a modern compiler, like GNU, Microsoft, IAR, Greenhills, etc., you could use either `int64_t` or `uint64_t` from `stdint`.  There are free modern compilers you can download, so no reason to use Turbo C++.

Comment: Open Watcom supports DOS targeting *and* `long long`.

Answer (score 4):

You are using a platform from the 1980s, before C++ even existed as a standard. Even your `int` is only 16-bit.

It's not clear what you want to use `long long` for but if you're after a 64-bit type you're out of luck. Either way, your compiler simply does not support this type. You'll have to come up with a workaround that does not require use of this type.

Or use a compiler from now times.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of writing `long long`, try writing   `long long int`   .
Assumption : The error generator echoes that `long long` is not recognised.